# Top fans not working bottom floor fans working

Tags: honda, hvac, crv

Recently in a Honda CR-V 2011 the top fans stopped working but the floor fans are working. I’ve checked under the hood and both fans are running. It seems like changing the ac control options on the dashboard have no effect but the light indicates switch as if they were. When pressing Max AC it was working but it is now stuck on floorboards no matter what the dashboard lights say.

I checked again and there is air coming out of the side vent lightly but not the two center vents. There is air coming out of the defrost too.

Comment: Are the fans not working or are you just not feeling any air coming from the top register? I can't think of a car which has multiple fans (there could be one, but I've not seen it). What manufacturers usually do is have a single fan which is then ducted and directed via blend doors. It's usually these doors which quit functioning. The doors are actuated by a motor and the motor quits doing its thing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I see. There are two fans spinning when looking under the hood and the engine is running but I'm not feeling anything coming out of the top vents.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The fans under your hood have nothing to do with the AC blower fan inside your car! And, as paulster2 stated, most cars have only 1 blower motor for your vents, and this is changed between floor, vent, and defrost, by doors that direct the air where desired. Yours is apparently not working, in some cars these are controlled by electric actuators and in some by vacuum lines.

Comment: @GlenYates I’ve updated my post